# How to use ParcelJS' hot reload server without bundling

Tags: webpack, watch, parceljs, hot-reload

I *love* ParcelJS' hot reload feature of its server command `serve`: On change of the watched directories things get bundled *and* the browser auto-reloads.

However I have a project where the watched directory (incl subdirectories) does not need to be bundled, but served as is. How can I serve this directory to a browser with  ParcelJS' `serve` command and keep the autoload feature in the browser?

Or can I do this with webpack? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you want to muck around with ParcelJS semi-internals, you can create your own middleware, watch the directory for changes with chokidar or similar, and then emit an update.

Webpack can do this with `webpack-dev-server` with the options `watchContentBase: true` and `contentBase: "<your public path>"`.

For a reference of webpack you can use [react-scripts config](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js).

ParcelJS (note: not tested and for V1 only - adapted from [ParcelJS Docs](https://parceljs.org/api.html)):

```js
const Bundler = require('parcel-bundler');
const Path = require('path');
const chokidar = require('chokidar');

// Bundler options
const options = {
  watch: true,
  hmr: true
};

(async function() {
  // Initializes a bundler using the entrypoint location and options provided
  const bundler = new Bundler(entryFiles, options);

  // Run the bundler, this returns the main bundle
  // Use the events if you're using watch mode as this promise will only trigger once and not for every rebuild
  const server = await bundler.start();
  chokidar.watch('<your public path>').on('all', (event, path) => {
    server.hmr.broadcast({
      type: "reload"
    });
  });
})();
```